# ejabberd my browser client is not connecting to server

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to connect my ejabberd but it is not connecting.I checked the ejabberd.log file but i am not getting the issue what it is exactly? I am new here so if anybody knows then please help me in starting the ejabberd on ubuntu 16.04.

ejabberd.log:

2017-03-16 10:00:09.903 [info] <0.481.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333 (#Port<0.12667>) Accepted connection ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:53524 -> ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:5280
2017-03-16 10:00:09.904 [info] <0.554.0>@ejabberd_http:init:158 started: {p1_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.12667>,#Port<0.12668>}}
2017-03-16 10:00:09.906 [info] <0.481.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333 (#Port<0.12669>) Accepted connection ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:53526 -> ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:5280
2017-03-16 10:00:09.907 [info] <0.555.0>@ejabberd_http:init:158 started: {p1_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.12669>,#Port<0.12670>}}
2017-03-16 10:00:09.919 [info] <0.481.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333 (#Port<0.12671>) Accepted connection ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:53528 -> ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:5280
2017-03-16 10:00:09.920 [info] <0.556.0>@ejabberd_http:init:158 started: {p1_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.12671>,#Port<0.12672>}}